# Is there a "get first item" function, for use in higher-ordered functions?

Tags: python, list, sequence, higher-order-functions

Say there is a list of tuples (or otherwise index-able items)

```
d = [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
```

that is to be sorted based on the first element in each item, as so

```
s = sorted(d, key = lambda i: i[0])
```

Is there a standard/built-in function for this "first" operation, such that it can be written similar to the following?

```
s = sorted(d, key = fn.first)
```

(Defining a local first function is trivial, but I am curious about a standard function like `operator.add` or similar.)

Comment: This is the natural sort order for `tuple` anyway. The difference is that when the first item compares equal, the comparison moves onto the second item and so on.

Comment: @gnibbler Good point. I was merely thinking of equality, not ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from the operator module.

```
from operator import itemgetter
s = sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Furthermore, you could design your own `first` operator.

```
first = itemgetter(0)
s = sorted(d, key=first)
```

Comment: Ahh, clever. I overlooked that.

Comment: It is more efficient than a lambda function.

Comment: Other than the optimization, what reasons would you ever want to use itemgetter? `lambda i: i[0]` doesn't require any imports and is more concise.

Comment: @whereswalden: because of the optimization, basically.